# place a div tag on top of other tags and relate position to another div

Tags: html, css, tags

First sorry for bad English.
I create the following code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="fa" dir="rtl" style="font-family: tahoma">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="st.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="ontop"></div>
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="sideRight"></div>
        <div id="center"></div>
        <div id="sideLeft"></div>
        <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width:1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#ontop{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: purple;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    right:20px;
    opacity:0.5;
}
#header{
    width: 94%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
#sideRight{
    width: 15%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
#center{
    width: 58%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
#sideLeft{
    width: 15%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
#footer{
    width: 94%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: blue;
    float: right;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
```

I want to position div with "ontop" id in 20px from right and 20px from top of **"container" div** and be **on top of** other div.in my code position of "ontop" div ,related to screen not "container" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be relative to the parent element, all you would have to do is add `position: relative` to the parent element. It is otherwise assumed to be absolutely positioned relative to the next relatively positioned parent element. Since there were none, it was relative to the window.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/27s96vxz/)

```
#container {
    width:1000px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; /* Added .. */
}
```

Comment: when i use relative position,it change the position of other divs.

Comment: @HosseinRashnoo Just add `position: relative` to `#container`.